# Regex optimization: negative character class "[^#]" nullifies multiline flag "m"

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse a text line by line, catching everything EXCEPT what's after a specific marker, `#` for example. No escaping to take into account, pretty basic.

For instance, if the input text is:

```
Multiline input text
Mid-sentence# cut, this won't be matched
Hey there
```

If want to retrieve

```
['Multiline input text',
 'Mid-sentence',
 'Hey There']
```

This is working fine with `/(.*?)(?:#.*$|$)/mg` (even though there are a few empty matches). However, if I try to improve the regex (by avoiding backtracking and getting rid of empty matches) with `/([^#]++)(?:#.*$|$)/mg`, it returns

```
[
"Multiline input text
Mid-sentence",
"
Hey There"
]
```

As if `[^#]` was including linebreaks, even with the multiline flag on. As far as I can tell I can fix that by adding `[^#\n\r]` into the class character, but this makes the multiline option kind of useless and I'm afraid it could break on some weird linebreaks in some environments/encoding.

Would any of you know the reason for this behavior, and if there's another workaround? Thanks!

**Edit**
Originally, it happens in PCRE. But even in Javascript with `/([^#]+)(?:#.*$|$)/mg`, same unwanted multiline behavior. I know I could probably use the language to parse the text line by line, but I'd like to do it with regex only.

Comment: You didn't say the language.  Regex behavior varies, so this matters.  It is probably simpler and faster to read an array of lines then erase the `#...` strings by substituting the empty string for them.  But again this depends on language.

Comment: You're right, I meant to mention that. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you got your definition of `/m` wrong. The only thing this flag does is to change what `^` and `$` matches, so that they also match at the beginning and end of line respectively. It does not affect anything else. If you don't want to match line breaks you should do as you suggested and use `[^#\n\r]`.

Comment: Yup, seems I got mixed up. The fix seems to be the actual solution, then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The regex that will work for you is:

```
^(.*?)(?:#.*|)$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/aP8eV6

DIfference is use of `.*?` instead of `[^#]+`.

- `[^#]+` by definition matches anything but `#` and that includes newlines as well.
- multiline flag `m` only lets you use line start/end anchors `^ and $` in multiline inputs.

Comment: Yep, that was my first regex. But performance-wise possessive quantifiers are better than lazy ones, and I think this was a good trivial example of where to use one, hence the `[^#]++`. You're right about the flag confusion though, so `[^#\n\r]++` seems to be my answer here.